# Dual-boot and virtualise Ubuntu/Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, virtualbox

I came across this post [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/625280/dual-boot-and-virtualize-both-windows-8-and-ubuntu) which discussed the idea of **dual-booting** Linux/Windows and **having the ability to spin up the other OS virtually** via something like virtualbox.

I also have a need for this in my workflow and wanted to find out if the caveats still exist seven years later and for win10.

**So a summary of the features**,

- Ubuntu (dual-boot 1st OS)
- Windows (dual-boot 2nd OS)
- From Ubuntu (host) access windows via virtualbox
- From Windows (host) access Ubuntu via virtualbox

I don't have a use case for the fourth, but I would much like to boot Ubuntu and have the **ability to load up Windows virtually without having to reboot**. Then on a separate occasion, boot Windows (natively) to access all the resources for something like gaming.

**Questions**,

1. Isn't the seoncd and third case solved possible simply using a vhd which can be virtually and natively booted from?
2. How will the device drivers and more importantly the Windows licence adapt to running the same OS bare bones and virtually?

Comment: AFAIK, the first and second cases is not possible. Ask why do you need those cases? You can mount Windows NTFS (generally) partitions in GNU/Linux distributions.

Comment: You can use physical disks in virtual box using [these instructions](https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html). I'm not sure if this would enable you to boot Windows, however. Another concern (to what you mentioned) is, if you are running a UEFI system, your boot partition will be mounted in Ubuntu already.

Comment: A use case, is it to run a Windows-only program, do a task and then close the VM, without having to reboot (from Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Only one Operating system can access and control bare hardware, we cannot have both accessing at the same time.

With virtualbox, you will be able to have GUEST OS running inside HOST OS. So if you boot with Ubuntu, then then install virtualbox in Ubuntu. Within virtualbox you can create Guest machine where you can install windows. However this windows will not be same as your dual boot. This windows (guest OS) will run only from vitual machine installed in ubuntu.

Update:
From windows as host, you will be able to run your dual boot ubuntu by following steps mentioned on this link... https://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329

However I still think it would not be very good idea to do so...

Comment: Why can't you run a Windows VM in Ubuntu using a physical partition? I've run Windows VMs off physical drives before, which is a somewhat similar situation. I'd imagine that UEFI systems with a boot partition (that would likely be mounted in Ubuntu) would pose an issue, though.

Comment: The VM creates a file in vmdk format (There are other format too). That is where it simulate the mbr etc. It is not possible for VM to access actual windows partition directly. It runs on top of Ubuntu and creates it's own virtual hardware.

Comment: I didn't mean running two bare bones OSs at the same time. I amended the post to make it clearer.